# Answers in the Hell question reflect a bad trend!

Tags: discussion

Reading through the answers to [this question on Hell](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/5656/which-is-hell-punishment-or-revenge) it looks like the people commenting on the answers have a better grasp of the sources behind the subject than the people who answered.

This is not so good.

For one thing, the question should be closed or edited since the answer looked for reflects a doctrine.  But if we're going to attempt to answer it, we need to do so with the Bible or other authoritative texts.

I think it's a good question.  But what needs to be defined in the question is not what is meant by punishment and revenge, but what is meant by Hell!

Answer (score 4):

This is a bad situation, because the question is great - it's the answers that are seeming to stink.  Lost Hobbit is trying to pick apart the purpose of hell using very standard terms - punishment versus revenge.

The answers are getting bogged down in the nature of hell.

The questions is really trying to get at difference between punishment and revenge, and its final manifestation.

I almost started linking to my question a while back on *The Great Divorce*, and God's omnipresence extending to hell, but looking at the discussion, I kinda wanted to stay out of that particular melee.

Comment: I was thinking about that book too, the only problem is, C.S. Lewis wouldn't want you to use his 'dream' as a theological basis for anything.

Comment: @Peter: While I'm sorely tempted to open up my personal Canon to just one more book by Lewis, _The Great Divorce_ isn't the one I'd pick. ;-)  I think it represents Lewis' personal conception of Hell, which will not have the same impact on other people.  At any rate, I submitted an answer based largely on the end of Revelation that I think represents the closest we have to a consensus among believers.  What do y'all think?

Comment: I think I got to be your first +1 :)

Comment: @Jon I liked the Great Divorce for it's emotional pull and the disclaimer that it's not supposed to be about purgatory or anything specific.  Just yet another cool awesome picture like the ends of Pilgrims Regress and The Last Battle.  However, using Revelation to make a consensus among Christians of different denominations is at the very least an uphill battle. I've gotta applaud you on that answer, it really set the bar up a notch.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the answers to that particular question are bad (Hey you!  Think so too?  Vote them down, not up!)

However, closing a good question because its answers are bad is, with respect, a silly idea.

Let someone come along and claim the necromancer tag for having a good answer later.

Comment: That's why I brought it up on meta, it looked like we were ignoring the whole, better specify your doctrine part.  That's why we'd want to close the question.  The problem is that people were answering it and not asking for the question to be improved.